# Magento2 Display page builder custom attribute value in custom PHTML

Tags: magento2, page-builder

Magento2 How can I display page builder product custom attribute value in custom PHTML file.

In short, I have created a product custom attribute of type page builder in admin & I want its value to be displayed in frontend (from custom.phtml)

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar thing (mind this is a product attribute)
in phtml file:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use Hyva\Theme\Model\ViewModelRegistry;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Hyva\Theme\ViewModel\ProductPage;

/** @var Escaper $escaper */
/** @var Template $block */
/** @var ViewModelRegistry $viewModels */

/** @var ProductPage $productViewModel */
$productViewModel = $viewModels->require(ProductPage::class);
/** @var Product $product */
$product = $productViewModel->getProduct();

if (!$product->getYourAttributeIdentifier()) {
    return;
}
?>



<div>
<?= $productViewModel->productAttributeHtml($product, $product->getYourAttributeIdentifier(), 'your_attribute_identifier') ?>
</div>
```

replace "your attribute identifier" with what you need and you're done! :) if it's not empty it will show